# pygeolib.GeocoderError: Error ZERO_RESULTS

Tags: python, geocoding

Use case: I am trying to extract the latitide and longitude of addresses that I have collected from a website using python geocoder package.

Problem: Whenever I execute the given code, I keep getting the GeoCodeError.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Ashish/PycharmProjects/Petrogeocode.py", line 13, in  <module>
address=Geocoder.geocode(addr)
File "C:\Users\Ashish\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site- packages\pygeocoder.py", line 129, in geocode
return GeocoderResult(Geocoder.get_data(params=params))
File "C:\Users\Ashish\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-  packages\pygeocoder.py", line 212, in get_data
raise GeocoderError(response_json['status'], response.url)
pygeolib.GeocoderError: Error ZERO_RESULTS
Query: https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?language=&region=&bounds=&components=&address=lot+1190%2C+mukim+bukit+tinggi+kepala+batas&sensor=false

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I searched SO for any possible solution, the closest I got was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13956615/googlemaps-geocoder-error-zero-results) but even if i remove the Zip code from the addresses, I still get the same error message.

The code is as follows

```
__author__ = 'Ashish'

from pygeocoder import Geocoder
from pygeolib import GeocoderError

bad_addr=open('bad_addr.txt','w') 
good_addr=open('good_addr.txt','w')

with open('sample.txt') as f:
addrlist=f.read().splitlines()

for addr in addrlist:
    address=Geocoder.geocode(addr) # read the first address in the list

    try:
        address=Geocoder.geocode(' '.join(addr)) # try to geocode it
        
        if not address.valid_address:
            bad_addr.write(str(address)) # if the address is not valid then write it to a file called bad_addr.txt
            bad_addr.write(str(address.coordinates)) # Also write the coordinates if found
            bad_addr.write("\n")
        else:
            good_addr.write(str(address)) # if the address is valid then write it to a file called good_addr.txt
            good_addr.write(str(address.coordinates))
            good_addr.write("\n")
         #   continue
    except GeocoderError:
        print "The address: ",addr," could not be geocoded" # catch the bad address exception thrown 
    

bad_addr.close() # close the file
good_addr.close() # close the file
f.close()
```

the sample.txt file has addresses like given below

```
34 jalan nilam 1/1, tmn perindustrian teknelogi tinggi subang
no.82, jalan enau 15, taman teratai, kangkar pulai
lot 1190, mukim bukit tinggi kepala batas
no.16 jalan tampoi 7/1 kawasan perindustrian tampoi johor bahru
no. 187, jalan skudai, batu 4 1/2, johor bahru
75 jalan tuanku antah, seremban, negeri sembilan
10, 10a, persiaran datoh (off jalan lahat), ipoh, perak
```

Please suggest what can I do in my code to solve this problem.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try  API's from other sources. Your addresses are not recognizable by Geocoder.

Answer (score -1):

For anyone who might run into the problem of the exception not being caught, make sure you have imported the Geocoder object from pygeolib. I missed that when I was troubleshooting.

```
from pygeolib import GeocoderError
```

Comment: The OP has done this already in the code posted above in question